# I have interfaced a matrix keypad

Tags: c, switch-statement, embedded, 8051, keypad

Every time I am entering in a case loop the last value gets reset by the key I press. But I want the last value I have updated whenever I enter in any case loop.

```
void menu()
{
    menu_no=key_pressed;
    
    switch (key_pressed)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            ID_set = menu_no;
            sprintf(menu_print,"Id%3d",ID_set); break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            digit_set = menu_no;
            sprintf(menu_print,"dig%2d",digit_set); break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            base_type_set = menu_no;
            sprintf(menu_print,"bt%3d",base_type_set); break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            voice_set = menu_no;
            sprintf(menu_print,"v%4d",voice_set); break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide examples for "the last value" and for "the key I press", i.e. tell a story like "when I do ... and then do ... then I observe that ... is ..., but I expect ... to be ...".  Please provide a [mre], so that it is not necessary to ask for the definitions of most of the identifiers in your code and e.g. where the value in `key_pressed` is coming from. I also get confused by what seems a needless copy of the value in `key_pressed` to `menu_no` mixed with uses of both, the copy and the original. Check [ask] and maybe the [tour].

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, and the code does not clarify. The code has nothing specific to embedded, keypad or 8081; you have rather over-tagged it.  Also all variables here are global; apart from https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/, without sight of the wider code, it may be difficult to answer in any event.

Comment: There is no loop in the code you show.